# how to set marginBottom in android listview or linearlayout Dynamically?

Tags: android, layout

friends,

i want to set layout_marginBottom using java code or dynamically

in list view or linearlayout

any one guide me how to achieve this?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ListView lst=getListView();

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                        );
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); //left,top,right,bottom
lst.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: or alternatively (if your listview is within a RelativeLayout) : RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: In case of setting only the bottom margin what could we do?

Answer (score 3):

For ListView, there is much more simpler method to change margin by Programmatically

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mListView
            .getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

But for LinearLayout, you can set margin from @UMAR answer. 
Have fun. @.@

Answer (score 0):

You can use setMargins. Look at official documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Ger

Answer (score 0):

to change margin dynamically using the animation:

```
Animation animMarginChange = new Animation() {

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
           ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mListView
            .getLayoutParams();
                  layoutParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
     }
};
 animMarginChange.setDuration(500); // in ms
 mListView.startAnimation(animMarginChange);
```