# Android: setMargin to ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want set margin to `listview` but after run application crashed !

My code :

```
final ListView lstContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstContent);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) lstContent.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100);
lstContent.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

This is xml code for layout

> XML:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnrArtistChange"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#272727"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:padding="11dp" android:visibility="gone">
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lstContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="@null" android:smoothScrollbar="true" android:animationCache="false" android:scrollingCache="false" android:divider="@null" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_marginTop="12dp" android:background="@null" android:scrollbars="none">

                </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya , No, My log cat error : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: I can solve this . show your xml

Comment: Thank you , i added xml to question

Comment: Can help me ? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can show your **Logcat** .

You can try with

```
      ListView lstContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstContent);   
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
      params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100); //left,top,right,bottom
      lstContent.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You can check **[how to change the layout margin for an Android ListView Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733382/how-to-set-marginbottom-in-android-listview-or-linearlayout-dynamically)**

Hope this helps you .